# AngularJs. Set value to model in isolate scope

Tags: angularjs, symfony, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

How can I pass a value from a select ng-model, which is created using the form.widget of the Symfony framework in the model, which is defined using the directive?

Template code:

```
<select name="post[vote][cinema]" ng-model="cinema" ng-change="set(cinema)">
<rating ng-model="cinema" max="max"></rating>
```

Html code:

```
<select name="post[vote][cinema]" ng-model="cinema" ng-change="set(cinema)">
<p class="dash ng-isolate-scope ng-valid ng-dirty" 
   ng-mouseleave="reset()" tabindex="0" role="slider" 
   aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="10" aria-valuenow="4" ng-model="cinema" max="max">
<a ng-repeat="r in range track by $index" 
   ng-mouseenter="enter($index + 1)" 
   ng-click="rate($index + 1)" ng-class="{...}" class="ng-scope"></a>
```

The problem is that if you select the rating value through the select element, it is assigned correctly only for the last element. And it is expected that specific select will interact with elements of the same model.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Zoomer/8s4m2e5e/54/

Comment: You have a bug, but it's not related to the code you posted in the question. First, don't reuse a controller for both the View and the directive - it can only lead to hard-to-trace bugs. Second, declare `set` on the scope, not on parent: `$scope.set = function(...`. And third, in `render` you probably wanted to set `$scope.valueselected = ngModelCtrl.$viewValue;`. http://jsfiddle.net/smtncL3q/1/

Comment: Oh, thank you! Here I am noob! I realized that the main mistake was - reuse, because of what I have lost in the $scope. Thus, the function $scope.set is not needed, because I can use $scope.rate to change the model in two cases.